# position objects in exact places in div

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an ASP.NET web app, I'm going to display some small icons on a div having an image as background. Div acts as a map and my small icons (images) are something like pins. These images have `style="position:relative; left:X, top:Y"`, I want them to be positioned in specific locations on the div, but they are not places exactly where I want, I think they affect on each other, how can I place them in my exact places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` on the pins, and `position:relative` on the map.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qdFeb/

Answer (score 1):

relative position adjusts it from it's original position.  So, setting left moves it that many pixels from it's original position, same with top.

You want to use absolute.

Answer (score 1):

use `position:absolute;` on the "pins" and `position:relative;` on the container `div`.

another method is to make one big `div` with the `background` as the `img` that you want, then fill it with smaller `div`s, and place the "pins" in those `div`s.